# awk matching only 1 lines with same pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk

The following awk script will add an entry `SAMPLE` to block `NOTES`. I have multiple blocks with the same name. What needs to be changed in this command to add the entry SAMPLE to first block NOTES only?

a class.txt with following content.

```
[serverClass:NOTES:new]
 whitelist.0=TEST
 whitelist.1=FRIDAY
 whitelist.2=SPOON
 whitelist.3=GAME29

[serverClass:NOTES]
 whitelist.0=TEST
 whitelist.1=FRIDAY
 whitelist.2=SPOON
 whitelist.3=GAME29

[serverClass:NOTES:new23]
 whitelist.0=TEST
 whitelist.1=FRIDAY
 whitelist.2=SPOON
 whitelist.3=GAME29sdf
```

after running this command

```
awk -vRS= -vORS='\n\n' '
  BEGIN{z="whitelist.0=SAMPLE";FS="\n"}
  /NOTES/{
    if (/[0-9]=/){
      split($NF, a, /[.=]/);
      sub(/0/, a[2]+1, z)
    }
    sub (/$/,"\n"z ,$0)
  };1' class.txt
```

output:

```
[serverClass:NOTES:new]
 whitelist.0=TEST
 whitelist.1=FRIDAY
 whitelist.2=SPOON
 whitelist.3=GAME29
 whitelist.4=SAMPLE    <-------

[serverClass:NOTES]
 whitelist.0=TEST
 whitelist.1=FRIDAY
 whitelist.2=SPOON
 whitelist.3=GAME29
 whitelist.4=SAMPLE    <-------

[serverClass:NOTES:new23]
 whitelist.0=TEST
 whitelist.1=FRIDAY
 whitelist.2=SPOON
 whitelist.3=GAME29sdf
 whitelist.4=SAMPLE    <-------
```

what need to be changed in above awk command to add to the block match [serverClass:NOTES] only?

expected:

```
[serverClass:NOTES:new]
 whitelist.0=TEST
 whitelist.1=FRIDAY
 whitelist.2=SPOON
 whitelist.3=GAME29

[serverClass:NOTES]
 whitelist.0=TEST
 whitelist.1=FRIDAY
 whitelist.2=SPOON
 whitelist.3=GAME29
 whitelist.4=SAMPLE    <-------  should be

[serverClass:NOTES:new23]
 whitelist.0=TEST
 whitelist.1=FRIDAY
 whitelist.2=SPOON
 whitelist.3=GAME29sdf
```

Comment: Please don't change the requirements of your question after posting it. This is not the same question you had asked before. You need to post a new question each time you need something different.

Comment: OP, in this case you should simply use `/NOTES]/` instead of `/NOTES/`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to use a variable and set its value to `1` the first time `NOTES` is found. Then, tell your script to only add the new entry if the variable is not `1`. For example:

```
awk -vRS= -vORS='\n\n' '
  BEGIN{z="whitelist.0=SAMPLE";FS="\n"}
  /NOTES/ && flag!=1{
    if (/[0-9]=/){
      split($NF, a, /[.=]/);
      sub(/0/, a[2]+1, z);
      flag=1;
    }
    sub (/$/,"\n"z ,$0)
  };1' infile
```